# How to delete duplicates after filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Microsoft Excel, I need to delete the rows that have duplicate info in a specific column, but just on the **filtered** data. When I use the "remove duplicates" function it also deletes the info that **wasn't** filtered. How can I use the "remove duplicates" only on the filtered data and not everything?

Comment: Is copying the visible values to a new sheet and de-duplicating on that set an option? Or do the values need to be de-duplicated within the original sheet?

Comment: Mmm that might work, I wanted an option without many steps but im going to try, thanks!

Comment: Copy the filtered range to the new WorkSheet and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select visible cells (home - find & select - special - visible cells only) only before removing duplicates.